# Cambiar el estilo de ciertas palabras en VS Code

Tags: html, css, vscode

**Buen día!**

Desde hace unos días estoy intentando hacerlo, pero no lo logro, ya que no me manejo muy bien con la API de VS Code para customización.

Necesito que los nombres de los selectores CSS aparezcan en cursiva/italica, **en la interfaz del editor de Visual Studio Code**, tanto en los archivos CSS como en los HTML, en los atributos `id=""` y `class=""` de una etiqueta.

La idea sería que lo que está entre un formas blancas quede con estilo de fuente itálica, cursiva, como se ve en las palabras clave require, include, while, etc, por ejemplo.
[image: En Archivo HTML]
[image: En Archivo CSS]

Por ejemplo, lo que está entre '|' deberia quedar con el estilo de fuente cursiva o itálica:

**Archivo CSS**

```css
|html| { 
  width: 100%; 
  font-size: 45px;
 }

|#id-ejemplo| {
  width: 75px; 
  font-size: 15px;
  color: red;
 }

|.clase-ejemplo| {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

**Archivo HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Ejemplo</h1>
  <div id="|id-ejemplo|">
    Holaaaaa
  </div>
  <div class="|clase-ejemplo|">
    Chauuuuu
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Hola SantiMedia, ¿podrías aportar datos para entender un poco mejor lo que deseas hacer?

Comment: Ahí la edité, perdon por no ser tan conciso. Gracias!

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el fin de ponerlo de ese modo en vs code.

Comment: Simplemente comodidad, queda visualmente más intuitivo que los selectores css queden en cursiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta la encontré cuando pude acceder a la documentación correcta ([Enlace a dicha documentación](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/08/syntax-highlighting-optimizations)), la comparto por si alguien tiene la curiosidad de hacer lo mismo que quise yo.
La solución constaba en colocar el siguiente código en settings.json de Visual Studio Code.

```js
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {// Configuramos el editor de código del VS Code
  "textMateRules": [ // Realizamos una nueva regla
    {
      "scope": [ // Configuramos el alcance de la configuración
        "meta.selector.css", // Selectores CSS en cualquier tipo de archivo
        "meta.attribute.class.html", // Valores de atributos class="solo-el-valor-aparece-en-italic"
        "meta.attribute.id.html" // Valores de atributos id="solo-el-valor-aparece-en-italic"
      ],
       "settings": { // Configuramos que estilo le aplicamos a los elementos dentro del alcance
         "fontStyle": "italic"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Otro link con información relacionada útil: [enlace](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers/)

Answer (score 1):

Hice una pequeña busqueda y al parecer lo solucionan añadiendo por ejemplo el siguiente codigo al **settings.json (ctrl + , or cmd + ,)**

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": [
        //following will be in italic (=FlottFlott)
        "comment",
        "entity.name.type.class", //class names
        "keyword", //import, export, return…
        "constant", //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
        "storage.modifier", //static keyword
        "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": "italic"
      }
    },
    {
      "scope": [
        //following will be excluded from italics (VSCode has some defaults for italics)
        "invalid",
        "keyword.operator",
        "constant.numeric.css",
        "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
        "constant.numeric.decimal.js",
        "constant.numeric.json"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

con esto los elementos indicados arriba se mostraran en "italic", seguroq eu ponerlo en cursiva no es muy dificil.

Answer (score 0):

Hola en el archivo "settings.json" deberás colocar el siguiente código:
 `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": { "textMateRules": [ {"scope": ["comment","entity.name.type.class","keyword","constant","storage.modifier","storage.type.class.js",],
"settings": {"fontStyle": "tahoma"}},{"scope": ["invalid","keyword.operator","constant.numeric.css","keyword.other.unit.px.css","constant.numeric.decimal.js","constant.numeric.json"],
"settings": {"fontStyle": ""}}]}`

Comment: Puedes explicar un poco tu respuesta por favor, ya que carece de justificación. ¡Muchas gracias!